# Why won't my late 2014 Mac mini output 4k video?

Tags: mac-mini, display

I have a Samsung U28D590 plugged into a Late 2014 Mac mini (with Iris video graphics) via Thunderbolt 2 to DisplayPort.

In the display options it does not give the option for 3840x2160, even after holding the option key while clicking on "Scaled"

Both the monitor and Mac mini support this resolution according to their documentation, so I wonder if I need to install some extra drivers or something like that.

Comment: Apple does not show it as supported? where did you read that?

Comment: @Buscar http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/

Comment: video output is what supports 4k. If your mirroring displays it only supports up to two displays at 2560 by 1600 pixels.

Comment: How would I know if I'm mirroring displays? I certainly didn't configure it that way.

Comment: I know that the mini supports 4k output, but Apple does not mention Samsung as supported monitor. http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856

Comment: That's news to me. I thought 4k video was 4k video, I didn't know the monitor needed to be supported separately.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of interest what is your screen refresh rate? 
needs to be low 30hz

Your problem could be related to the Iris graphics chip, just read a few
posts mentioning it could be the Iris causing the problems.

What version of Yosemite are you running?

Comment: version 10.10.1

Comment: Hmm have you tried, using just a hdmi cable instead of the thunderbolt 2/display port cable.